# Passing DateTime or String type that looks like a date as parameter to URL / (.net webapi)

Tags: .net, datetime, asp.net-web-api, routes, controller

Got a entity named `Item` with a `DateTime` date field which is configured with data annotation `Column(TypeName="Date")]` (stores only date without a time to db).

In my controller i have a `GET` method that should return a list of results. Method's `parameter / url` should **look** like a date but doesnt need to be a date, i guess.

Example: `www.localhost:port/16-3-2021`

1. Do i use `DateTime` as parameter or `String`, which is easier/better?
2. If parameter is `string`, how do i parse it correcly to a short date (with **formatting** like above) so i can say:

> db.Items.Where(item => item.Date == date)

3. If parameter is `DateTime` how do i configure routing to match the given format (like above)?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, whole approach looks incorrect to me and it seems that using Entity Framework would solve your problems with types.
To answer your questions:

1. You can only use `string` in `url`.
2. If I understood correctly, you only need a method to get a `string` out of your `Item` class like below

```
public class Item {

    Date date { get; set; }

    public dateToString()
    {
         return $"{this.date.Day}-{this.date.Month}-{this.date.Year}";
    }
}
```

3. Just use `dateToString` every time you need to pass `date` as a `string` so you don't lose your format.

Comment: I'm actually using EntityFramework. BUT supported format is `2021-03-16` per https://xkcd.com/1179/ . And what i need is `16-03-2021` in the URL and then somehow parse it or whatever needs to be done so i can filter by my `DateTime` property of `Item` class. Somewhere in repo i should go `db.Items.Where(item => item.Date == date)` or so.